# Is it possible to create an alert in Zabbix via API?

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-api, zabbix-custom-reports

I have a clarification regarding the Zabbix monitoring system.

Is it possible to create an alert via API in Zabbix? I found many ways to send alerts from Zabbix to other systems but didn't find a way to create an alert in Zabbix from third party applications like slack.

So what i would like to have a reversal method of creating these in Zabbix.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a trigger via API, see [trigger/create](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/api/reference/trigger/create)

What you probably want is to send data to a Zabbix item, in order to trigger a Problem: you use the Zabbix Sender, see

- official CLI https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/concepts/sender
- third party Python implementation https://github.com/adubkov/py-zabbix